# How to represent two models relation with 2 different association in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models, users and subjects.
There are two types of users

1. Teacher
2. Student

in the users model, type of users are distinguished by an attribute role.

So the problem here, I have two relations between the two models,
the first relation is "Teacher can create many subjects, Subjects belong to 1 teacher"
the other relation is "Student can register many subjects, Subjects can be registered by many students".

How to represent model, migration, factory for such design in Laravel?

Comment: a many to many relationship between users and subjects should do. whether teachers own subjects or students register subjects should be dealt with in your app

Answer (score 0):

two models-->users and subjects, users->teacher, students

```
php artisan make:model Teacher
php artisan make:model Student
php artisan make:model Subject
```

three models are created then, In Teacher model

```
public function subject()
{
  return $this->belongsTo("App\http\controllers\Subject",id);
}
```

where id is the teacher roll id, then In Subject model

```
public function teacher()
{
  return $this->hasMany("App\http\Controllers\Teacher");
}
```

Student can register many subjects , Subjects can be registered by many students

In Student model

```
public function subject()
{
  return $this->hasMany("App\Http\Controllers\Subject");
}
```

in this hasMany is refers to it can gets all registered books of certain student.

In Subject model

```
public function student()
{
  return $this->belongsTo("App\Https\Controllers\Student");
}
```

In controller

```
public function teacher($id)
{
  $teacher=Teacher::with('subject')->where('id',$id)->get();
}
```

it get all subjects created by teacher

```
public function students()
{
  $students=Student::with("subject")->with("id",Auth::user()->id)->get();
}
```

it can get all students registered books